# Getting FRF from FFT

Tags: fft

I have the FFT of a sensor output data. Is there any way to get frequncy response function FRF from this. I dont have any input data. Plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any knowledge of the input data then you can't really calculate the frequency response. However if you happen to know that input signal is e.g. white noise, then you can at least get an approximation of the *magnitude* of the frequency response.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. How can I use MATLAB to get FRF with white noise as input?

Comment: You probably need to post that as a separate question as I'm not a MATLAB expert, but it should be pretty simple - you just need to plot the *magnitude* of the FFT of the output signal to get a power spectrum *estimate*. You'll get a better plot if you can average successive power spectrum estimates (this will remove some of the variance resulting from using a finite amount of white noise as input).

Comment: But if you are using white noise as input, its FFT will just be a flat line for all frequency bins. So basically, for this input, the FFT of the sensor output data is identical to the FRF. @Paul_R, do you agree?

Comment: @Daniel: two problems - you can only get the *magnitude* of the FRF (there is no useful *phase* information available) and because you are only using a finite window the FFT of the output will only give you an *estimate* of the power spectrum. Averaging can help with this second part.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestions.I need magnitude of FRF alone which I will use in damage detection of a structure. I need just an estimate of frf as i need to just spot the peaks. will your suggestion suffice this. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Krishna: OK - you just need to make sure that you can excite your structure with something close to white noise. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for shedding time n effort.I am trying to do on the same lines!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Taking the IFFT (basically the FFT) of the FFT output data will give get you back into the time domain.</strike>

Sorry for the above answer, which doesn't address the question. To be more helpful, IIRC, the FRF is the ratio of the FFT of the response (output) to the FFT of the
excitation (input). Since you only have the FFT of the output, I'd say that there is no way to obtain the FRF from this alone.